# Execute dplyr::select with dplyr::across

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data (`df_1`):

```
df_1 <- structure(list(var_1 = c(99.4726192392409, 25.9155194833875), 
var_2 = c(99.9599985964596, 20.3848657943308), var_3 = c(93.1612774543464, 
31.651863809675), var_4 = c(54.2802151478827, 81.9601702317595
), var_5 = c(88.1385736726224, 94.7823309898376), var_6 = c(83.7288120947778, 
72.2155329957604), groups = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried:

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 %>% 
  select_at(.vars = 'var_1')

      var_1
1  99.47262
10 25.91552
```

It's ok. But:

```
df_1 %>% 
  select(across(.cols = 'var_1'))
```

> Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.

How to adjust this last function with `select` and `across`?

Comment: Can you show you package version

Comment: @akrun dplyr `‘0.8.99.9002’`

Comment: thanks, I don't find any examples in their github pagee with select and across.  I find in across.R  `Because `across()` is used within functions like `summarise()` and
#'   `mutate()`, you can't select or compute upon grouping variables.`

Comment: or in [select](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/select.R)

Comment: BTW, `select` can take both unuqoted and quoted.  So, I am not sure why there should be `across` `df_1 %>% select('var_1')`

Comment: I used this simple case to give the example, just.

Comment: Can you show an example where `across` is needed i.e. you cannot use the `select` directly with a vector of column names as strings?

Comment: I just thought that there could be a way to combine both functions.

Comment: May be in the future, they may include that option as a generalized way.  Deprecation of `_at/_all` suggests that the behavior should be similar across all functions.

Comment: Just wonder if `_if` is getting deprecated, then across may be needed

Comment: Hi @neves, you will likely find the [row-wise](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/rowwise.html) and [column-wise](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/colwise.html) vignettes helpful to understand the use case for `across`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `github` page for [select](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/select.R) or [across](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/across.R), there is no use case where `select` is used along with `across`.  According to `?across` documentation

> across() makes it easy to apply the same transformation to multiple columns, allowing you to use select() semantics inside in summarise() and mutate(). across() supersedes the family of "scoped variants" like summarise_at(), summarise_if(), and summarise_all(). See vignette("colwise") for more details.

It is not mentioned to be used along with `select`

In the current version, `select` can take unquoted and quoted variables

```
library(dplyr)
df_1 %>%
       select('var_1')
#     var_1
#1  99.47262
#10 25.91552

df_1 %>% 
     select('var_1', 'var_2')
#      var_1    var_2
#1  99.47262 99.96000
#10 25.91552 20.38487


df_1 %>% 
      select(var_1, var_2)
```

Or make use of `select_helpers` `starts_with/ends_with/matches/contains`

```
df1_1 %>% 
      select(starts_with('var'))
#       var_1    var_2
#1  99.47262 99.96000
#10 25.91552 20.38487
```